How to map bounding boxes effectively
I'm working on an OCR task. I have bounding boxes and a probabilistic mask predicted by my model.
I developed an algorithm that creates lines (merging bounding boxes) based on a probabilistic mask.
I also have an algorithm that maps bounding boxes to lines, but it takes quite a long time for me. I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to do this?
I provided code which implements my mapping approach. You can run it to reproduce my results.
The presented mapping approach шы the intersection of the line and the bounding box over the area of the bounding box. Then we take the maximum intersection values for each bounding box. As I said, it works well, but it takes a long time.
Thanks.
Code to reproduce:
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np
import pyclipper
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon


def plot(image,si=[12,12]):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=si);ax.imshow(image,cmap='gray')
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False);ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.show()  


def bbox_from_points(
        points: np.ndarray,
    ) -> np.ndarray:
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(points)
        points = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        area = (rect[1][0] + 1) * (1 + rect[1][1])
        length = 2 * (rect[1][0] + rect[1][1]) + 2
        distance = area * 1.5 / length  # compute distance to expand polygon
        offset = pyclipper.PyclipperOffset()
        offset.AddPath(points, pyclipper.JT_ROUND, pyclipper.ET_CLOSEDPOLYGON)
        _points = offset.Execute(distance)
        idx = 0
        if len(_points) > 1:
            max_size = 0
            for _idx, p in enumerate(_points):
                if len(p) > max_size:
                    idx = _idx
                    max_size = len(p)
            _points = [_points[idx]]
        expanded_points: np.ndarray = np.asarray(_points) 
        if len(expanded_points) < 1:
            return None  
        return  np.roll(cv2.boxPoints(cv2.minAreaRect(expanded_points)), -1, axis=0)


def draw(img, polygons, color=(255, 0, 0)):
    for p in polygons:
        cv2.polylines(
            img, 
            [p], 
            True, 
            color,
            thickness=1,
        )
    return img


def draw_mapping(img, lines, bboxes, mapping):
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        color = list(np.random.random(size=3) * 256)
        mask = mapping == i
        
        if not np.any(mask):
            continue
        
        local_bboxes = bboxes[mask]
        
        img = draw(img, local_bboxes, color=color)
        img = draw(img, np.expand_dims(line, axis=0), color=color)
        
    return img


def bboxes_from_bin_map(bin_map):
    
    boxes = []
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(bin_map, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for contour in contours:
        bbox = bbox_from_points(np.squeeze(contour))
        boxes.append(bbox)
    return np.asarray(boxes)


def lines_from_bin_map(bin_map):
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (20, 3))
    bin_map = cv2.morphologyEx(bin_map, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(bin_map, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    lines = np.zeros((len(contours), 4, 2))
    for i, contour in enumerate(contours):
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contour)
        line = cv2.boxPoints(rect, points=contour)
        lines[i] = line
    return lines, bin_map


def poly_intersection(poly_a: Polygon,
                      poly_b: Polygon) -> float:
    """Calculate the intersection area between two polygons."""
    assert isinstance(poly_a, Polygon)
    assert isinstance(poly_b, Polygon)
    if poly_a.intersects(poly_b):
        poly_obj = poly_a.intersection(poly_b)
        area = poly_obj.area
    else:
        area = 0.0
    return area


def intersection_over_bbox(lines, bboxes) -> np.ndarray:
    iob_matix = np.zeros((lines.shape[0], bboxes.shape[0]))
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        line = Polygon(line)        
        for j, bbox in enumerate(bboxes):
            bbox = Polygon(bbox)
            intesection_area = poly_intersection(bbox, line)
            iob = intesection_area / bbox.area
            iob_matix[i, j] = iob
    return iob_matix


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    img = cv2.imread("./orig.jpg")
    bin_map = cv2.imread('./bin_map.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    
    bboxes = bboxes_from_bin_map(bin_map)
    lines, bin_map_lines = lines_from_bin_map(bin_map)
    
    start = time.time()
    iob_matrix = intersection_over_bbox(lines, bboxes)
    lines2bboxes_mapping = iob_matrix.argmax(axis=0)
    print(f"Time: {time.time() - start:.4}")
    
    bboxes = bboxes.astype(np.int32)
    lines = lines.astype(np.int32)
    
    plot(bin_map)
    plot(draw(img.copy(), bboxes))
    plot(bin_map_lines)
    plot(draw_mapping(img, lines, bboxes, lines2bboxes_mapping))

Source images:


